# Issue Sending Request from gRPC Java Client

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I have this code:

```
ManagedChannel channel = ManagedChannelBuilder.forAddress("localhost", 9090).usePlaintext().build();
SentenceClassificationServiceGrpc.SentenceClassificationServiceBlockingStub SentenceClassificationStub = SentenceClassificationServiceGrpc.newBlockingStub(channel);

SentenceClassificationRequest request = SentenceClassificationRequest.newBuilder().setDocument("hey").setThreshold(1);
SentenceClassificationResponse response = SentenceClassificationStub.classification(request);
```

and I keep on getting this error:

java: incompatible types: com.application.SentenceClassificationRequest.Builder cannot be converted to com.application.SentenceClassificationRequest

I've generated the gRPC Java files using the Maven plugin. After looking at multiple examples I'm not sure what my issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution**

You forgot to build your *SentenceClassificationRequest*, currently you're assigning your *SentenceClassificationRequest.Builder* to *SentenceClassificationRequest*

Just add **.build()** to the end of the builder

```
SentenceClassificationRequest request = SentenceClassificationRequest.newBuilder().setDocument("hey").setThreshold(1).build();
```

Comment: Oh dear...I've been struggling with this for longer than I'd care to admit. Thank you for this. Worked like a charm.